# Can't install any thing due to "The following packages have unmet dependencies:"

Tags: package-management

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
apport : Depends on  python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.16) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15 is to be installed

apport-gtk : Depends on python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.16) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15 is to be installed

jq : Depends on libjq1 (= 1.5+dfsg-1.3~eugenesan~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: What Ubuntu are you using?, and please provide the command used (ie. what are you installing).  As for errors, a quick scan of `python3-apport` shows [2.20.1..]*2.15* is being the correct (& *2.17* in updates *so try updating your repolists with `sudo apt update`*) package for Xenial (16.04, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-apport&searchon=names) and no *2.16* being supported so you have something non-standard (or non-ubuntu) in your sources..

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libjq1 python3-apport apport apport-gtk` (add to question)?

Comment: Ubuntu version 16.04 
Any thing i install, i get this error!